# Display and move image

Tags: swift

I have this piece of code that makes an image move, but I want this to be displayed 5 seconds after I open a page.

How do I do this? Thanks

```
@IBOutlet weak var moveobj: UIImageView!



override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {


    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    let orbit = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position")
    var affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.0)
    affineTransform = CGAffineTransformRotate(affineTransform, CGFloat(M_PI))
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: CGPoint(x: 198 - (100/2),y: 135 - (100/2)), radius:  CGFloat(155), startAngle: CGFloat(255), endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI * 2 ), clockwise: true)


    orbit.path = circlePath.CGPath
    orbit.duration = 18
    orbit.additive = true
    orbit.repeatCount = 0.15
    orbit.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced


    moveobj.layer .addAnimation(orbit, forKey: "orbit")
```

Comment: So you want to display the image for 5 seconds?

Comment: no i want to display this image 5 seconds after  i open a page and began to move

Comment: for example i open a page wait 5 second and this began to move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To wait 5 seconds before you do anything you can use a `Timer`, see below how to use it:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // start a new timer with an interval of 5 seconds
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.showImage), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}

// after 5 seconds this class will be called and here you can do your work
func showImage(){
    print("Showing")
}
```

Comment: i put this but this don´t do anything

Comment: Did you use my solution? If yes, consider accepting it so that others can benefit from it in the future.

Comment: yes, its was my problem  i forgot to put if call function self.function .... but now its works thkx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it what you are looking for. Aside from using a timer like Rashwan suggested, you can use [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch).

In `viewDidAppear()`, show the picture, then add the following code for 5 seconds delay, Something like this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    loadImage()

    let delayInSeconds = 5.0
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
        Int64(delayInSeconds * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //You can add some "finish up" operations here 
    }
}
```

Comment: i put this but this don´t do anything

Comment: Where do you put it? What executes before? After?

Comment: And yes, it's not doing anything for 5 seconds.